# Email Thread Messages using JavaMail API

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

How to identify that particular message is email thread and retrieving messages in that thread using JavaMail API?

for email

```
 A replies to B
   B replies to A
      A emails to B (Original Message)
```

How to fetch information about this thread?

Thank you

Comment: Have you find the proper implementation for this issue as I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 5256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256) describes an IMAP extension to support threading.  Not a lot of servers support it, and JavaMail doesn't support it.  If you need to implement the threading algorithm yourself in your application, the RFC includes some references that might be helpful.

Gmail provides a non-standard API to get the "thread ID" for a message.  You can use the [JavaMail gimap provider](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html) to access this information.