# Email Thread Messages using JavaMail API Reading

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

How to identify that particular message is email thread and retrieving messages in that thread using JavaMail API?

for email

```
 A replies to B
   B replies to A
      A emails to B (Original Message)
```

This question is referenced to the same thread.

[Email Thread Messages using JavaMail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837843/email-thread-messages-using-javamail-api)

But Still could not find proper way of implementing this.
have anyone succeeded in doing this. I know we need to have this "algorithm thread" implemented but how we could implement. as I am using JavaMail version 1.5.6.

Comment: Actually there is no proper way to fetch. But you may get the header information for each mail and check Reply-to or refenreces tags to create relation for each mail.  But the important thing,the referenced mail can be located in any folder, moved or even deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting another issue. when A sends email to B its perfectly fine. then A again reply to same message to B. then I'm not getting that message. I have checked my inbox its not there. what can be the possible reason ?

Comment: You can do this by inspecting the "In-Reply-To" and "References" headers of the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no proper way of doing that. Sometimes your server does not have compulsory extensions installed in it. for your issue you must have sort and thread extension installed in it.

Although you can use this link for reference.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256

If some more info you need just reply to my Answer.

Comment: It is possible to infer threading using the "In-Reply-To" and "References" headers of a message.

Comment: Yes, That's the  solution for this. Thanks to add that.